# Why doesn't the code operate accordingly?

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm trying to write this code in such way that each click on the button changes the color of the panel.  I want it to cycle from red>green>blue>gray>red>... and so on.
this is how my listener class looks like

```
private class Listener implements ActionListener
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent action)
  {
     if(getBackground() == Color.RED)
        setBackground(Color.GREEN);
     else if(getBackground() == Color.GREEN)
        setBackground(Color.BLUE);
     else if(getBackground() == Color.BLUE)
        setBackground(Color.GRAY);
     else
        setBackground(Color.RED);

     setBackground(Color.RED);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say what's wrong but from your code it looks like it's always setting the background to red.  Remove the `setBackground(Color.RED);` line that's after the `if`/`else` block so that stops overwriting whatever color was set by the `if` and it might start working.  If not then try using `getBackground().equals(Color.RED)` to compare colors instead of using `==`.

Comment: im sorry, what happens is that the screen turns red on the first click, but then nothing happens when subsequent clicks result

Comment: Ok, as I guessed.  Remove the 3rd-to-last line in the code you posted - that's outside the if/else blocks so it's setting it to red every time you call the method.  All you want to run are the calls inside the if/else blocks.

Comment: yes, youre 100% correct.  But why would == work here?

Comment: `==` is working because every color you use is a reference to one of the static colors defined in the `Color` class.  In this case you actually are referencing the same objects in memory so `==` works, but if you start creating new colors (like allowing custom, user-defined colors to be used) it probably will break.  It's bad practice to get in the habit of expecting `==` to work on objects but there are times when it's valid.

Comment: thank you for your detailed and brilliant answer.  I understand it now.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `==` operator to compare. Use [`equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method of Color class.

`==` operator checks whether both are refering same object in the memory.

Use [`equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method to check whether both are meaningfully equal or not.

> Determines whether another object is equal to this Color. The result
>   is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a Color object
>   that has the same red, green, blue, and alpha values as this object.

Comment: oh so for colors i need .equals()? I thought each color was represented as an object tho?

Comment: by the way i tried it and it didnt change anything??

Comment: You should always use `.equals()` unless you're comparing either primative types (`int`, `char`, etc, which don't have methods on them) or enum values (which are static references).

Answer (score 1):

The final line of your function, the unconditional:

```
setBackground(Color.RED);
```

sets the background color to red ***always.*** You need to get rid of that line.

What's happening is that the color is being set to red the first time you call the function (it may briefly become another color depending on it's initial value). Then, on ***every*** subsequent call, it will be set to green for a very short period of time, then back to red.

In addition, you should be using `equals` for object *value* equality in Java, `==` should be reserved for object *reference* equality (`==` *may* work depending on how the color objects are managed under the covers but it's not guaranteed).

Implementing both those changes will see you with something like:

```
private class Listener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent action) {
        if(getBackground().equals(Color.RED))
            setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        else if(getBackground().equals(Color.GREEN))
            setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        else if(getBackground().equals(Color.BLUE))
            setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        else
            setBackground(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The final line of the method, which sets the color to red, is unconditional, which means it sets the color to red every time the method is called. Try to remove this line.